# Mongoose error cyclic dependency detected

Tags: javascript

So I am making a discord moderation bot, because I don't really trust public bots, for some reasons
and I keep getting the error, I have autoIndex: false inside of index.js i've reached out to some other people and they could not help me either

```
Error: cyclic dependency detected
    at serializeObject (C:\Users\ihate\OneDrive\Documents\Perth Points\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:333:34)
    at serializeInto (C:\Users\ihate\OneDrive\Documents\Perth Points\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:941:17)
    at serializeObject (C:\Users\ihate\OneDrive\Documents\Perth Points\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (C:\Users\ihate\OneDrive\Documents\Perth Points\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:837:17)
    at serializeObject (C:\Users\ihate\OneDrive\Documents\Perth Points\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (C:\Users\ihate\OneDrive\Documents\Perth Points\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:941:17)
    at serializeObject (C:\Users\ihate\OneDrive\Documents\Perth Points\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (C:\Users\ihate\OneDrive\Documents\Perth Points\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:941:17)
    at serializeObject (C:\Users\ihate\OneDrive\Documents\Perth Points\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (C:\Users\ihate\OneDrive\Documents\Perth Points\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:941:17)
    at serializeObject (C:\Users\ihate\OneDrive\Documents\Perth Points\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (C:\Users\ihate\OneDrive\Documents\Perth Points\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:941:17)
    at serializeObject (C:\Users\ihate\OneDrive\Documents\Perth Points\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (C:\Users\ihate\OneDrive\Documents\Perth Points\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:941:17)
    at BSON.serialize (C:\Users\ihate\OneDrive\Documents\Perth Points\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\bson.js:64:28)
    at Msg.serializeBson (C:\Users\ihate\OneDrive\Documents\Perth Points\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\msg.js:126:22)
```

Here is the source :D

```
//DB Connect (I removed the password)
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://perthpoints:passwordHere@cluster0.hepyv.mongodb.net/Index?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    autoIndex: false
})
```

```
//DB Schema
let warnSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Warns    : Array,
    userID   : String,
    serverID : String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("warns", warnSchema);
```

-- Warn command
https://hasteb.in/gedevahu.js

If you have any idea why it keeps doing this please tell me why...
Cause I don't know why, it was working fine before